# How can I Save Elements Appended Onto A List Of Lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists filled with songs and artists

e.g list = [[artist1, song1],[artist2, song2]]

How can I use an external file to save the elements appended for next time I open the code

e.g list.append([artist3, song3])

and those elements will save onto the list even when I close the code and open it back up

Comment: Welcome to SO. Make sure to tag your questions with a language ([tag:python]?)

Comment: If this is Python, have a look at [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Answer (score 0):

We use the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module for that purpose.

```
import pickle
songs_list = [[artist1, song1],[artist2, song2]]

#save
pickle.dump(songs_list, 'filename.txt')#saves the list into 'filename.txt'


#load
old_songs_list = pickle.load('filename.txt')#loads the list from 'filename.txt'
```